# Dynamic outlier detection using window in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, series

I want to implement outlier detection which will use a window to check whether the next element is an outlier or not. Let's say we use a window of length 3 on pd.Series like this: [0,1,2,3,4]. I would calculate median and mad (or mean and std) on [0,1,2] and check whether 3 is an outlier.
I implemented a for-loop solution but it's really slow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say you start with

```
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 1, 4, 2000, 2])
```

Then using [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html), the following will show you that the 5th element is 200 away from a length-3 window median:

```
(s - s.rolling(3).median()).abs() > 200
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
dtype: bool
```

It is vectorized, and therefore should be much faster than a `for` loop.

Comment: Can you please take a look at my updated question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50227080/dynamic-outlier-detection-using-window-in-pandas-without-rolling-object

Comment: :-) I just did.