# Outlier detection based on the moving mean in Python

Tags: python, pandas, outliers, rolling-computation

I am trying to translate an algorithm from MATLAB to Python. The algorithm works with large datasets, and need an outlier detection and elimination technique to be applied.

In the MATLAB code, the outlier deletion technique I use is [movmedian](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movmedian.html#:%7E:text=M%20%3D%20movmedian(%20A%20%2C%20%5Bkb%20kf%5D%20)%20computes,backward%2C%20and%20kf%20elements%20forward.&text=For%20example%2C%20if%20x%20is,to%20the%20times%20in%20x%20.):

```
   Outlier_T=isoutlier(Data_raw.Temperatura,'movmedian',3);
   Data_raw(find(Outlier_T),:)=[]
```

Which detects outliers with a rolling median, by finding desproportionate values *in the centre of a three value moving window*. So If I have a column "Temperatura" with a 40 on row 3, it is detected and the entire row is deleted.

```py
         Temperatura     Date       
    1        24.72        2.3        
    2        25.76        4.6        
    3        40           7.0        
    4        25.31        9.3        
    5        26.21       15.6
    6        26.59       17.9        
   ...        ...         ...
```

To my understanding, this is achieved with [pandas.DataFrame.rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html). I have seen several posts examplify its use, but I am not managing to make it work with my code:

**Attempt A:**

```
Dataframe.rolling(df["t_new"]))
```

**Attempt B:**

```
df-df.rolling(3).median().abs()>200
```

#based on @Ami Tavory's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50208410/13100360)

*Am I missing something obvious here?* What is the right way of doing this?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: There is a typo. Try replacing `meadian` with `median`

Comment: Sorry, I wrote this but the typo is not in the code

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Posted an answer below that uses rolling median.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Code below drops the rows based on threshold. This threshold could be adjusted as needed. Not sure if it replicates Matlab code though.

```
# Import Libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Temperatura': [24.72, 25.76, 40, 25.31, 26.21, 26.59],
    'Date':[2.3,4.6,7.0,9.3,15.6,17.9]
})

# Set threshold for difference with rolling median
upper_threshold = 1
lower_threshold = -1

# Calculate rolling median
df['rolling_temp'] = df['Temperatura'].rolling(window=3).median()

# Calculate difference
df['diff'] = df['Temperatura'] - df['rolling_temp']

# Flag rows to be dropped as `1`
df['drop_flag'] = np.where((df['diff']>upper_threshold)|(df['diff']<lower_threshold),1,0)

# Drop flagged rows
df = df[df['drop_flag']!=1]
df = df.drop(['rolling_temp', 'rolling_temp', 'diff', 'drop_flag'],axis=1)
```

Output

```
print(df)

   Temperatura  Date
0        24.72   2.3
1        25.76   4.6
3        25.31   9.3
4        26.21  15.6
5        26.59  17.9
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am running in to this error: File "home/.../pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 4404, in get_value
 return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
KeyError: 445

Comment: Could you post a sample DataFrame that created the error? I am hoping the above code runs just fine on your side with the DataFrame in the answer?

Comment: Update: This line of code seems to generate the error: 
Before getting to it, the code identifies the outlier of '40' correctly, and assigns a 1 to it in column *drop_flag*
df = df[df['drop_flag']!=1]

Comment: ok. The code posted in answer runs fine on my computer. (1) could you confirm if the above code as-is runs on your side without error?, (2) could you post the error and the `DataFrame` that causes error?

Comment: I solved the problem. Your code works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Great. Thank you.

Comment: Could I just ask (sorry for not doing so in the above comment): If I change thresholds to 2 and -2, would that mean considering 5 values instead of 3?

Comment: No problem. (1) It is just how boarder net you want to cast to say that a data point is not an outlier. For example: `-2` and `2` would have a broader range of `-2 to 2` for a difference to be not outlier. Whereas `-1 to 1` would be a smaller range. Thus, with a larger range, the `difference` would have to be much larger for it to be an outlier.  (2) "... would that mean considering 5 values instead of 3 .. ": If I am correct, here I think you are referring to `window=3`. If `5` is selected here, it would be a rolling median of `5` data points instead of `3`. Thus, the differences could change

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, based on Nilesh Ingle's answer. Modified to be more general, verbose (graphs!), and a percentage threshold instead of the data's real values.

```py
# Calculate rolling median
df["Temp_Rolling"] = df["Temp"].rolling(window=3).median()

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
df["Temp_Scaled"] = scaler.fit_transform(df["Temp"].values.reshape(-1, 1))

df["Temp_Rolling"] = scaler.fit_transform(df["Temp_Rolling"].values.reshape(-1, 1))

# Calculate difference
df["Temp_Diff"] = df["Temp_Scaled"] - df["Temp_Rolling"]

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Set threshold for difference with rolling median
upper_threshold = 0.4
lower_threshold = -0.4

# Flag rows to be keepped True
df["Temp_Keep_Flag"] = np.where( (df["Temp_Diff"] > upper_threshold) | (df["Temp_Diff"] < lower_threshold), False, True)

# Keep flagged rows
print('dropped rows')
print(df[~df["Temp_Keep_Flag"]].index)
print('Your new graph')
df_result = df[df["Temp_Keep_Flag"].values]
df_result["Temp"].plot()
```

Once you're satisfied with the data cleaning

```py
# Satisfied, replace data
df = df[df["Temp_Keep_Flag"].values]
df.drop(columns=["Temp_Rolling", "Temp_Diff", "Temp_Keep_Flag"], inplace=True)
df.plot()
```

Comment: Julius, I like your comment. but just for clarity, you never define df_scaled in your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Nilesh answer works perfectly, to iterate on his code you could also do :

```
upper_threshold = 1
lower_threshold = -1

# Calculate rolling median
df['rolling_temp'] = df['Temp'].rolling(window=3).median()
# all in one line 
df = df.drop(df[(df['Temp']-df['rolling_temp']>upper_threshold)|(df['Temp']- df['rolling_temp']<lower_threshold)].index) 
# if you want to drop the column as well
del df["rolling_temp"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I am not able to make Nilseh's code work as you did. I edited my original post with the obtained error. Any idea why this is ocurring?

Comment: Not sure, it could be many several things. Could you try with just my version? It could also be an indexing issue. Where is the value 445 in your df?